# mysql docker image how to create databases with their own username and password

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker image as follows:

```
version: '3.6'
    
services: 
    # MySQL
    db:
        image: mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: user
       
        ports:
          # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
          - '3306:3306' 
        expose:
          # Opens port 3306 on the container
          - '3306'          
        volumes: 
            - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

The init folder directory is as follows:

```
init
   01.sql
```

The 01.sql is defined as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test`;
GRANT ALL ON `test`.* TO 'user'@'%';
```

When I execute docker-compose up the two databases are created successfully, but both mydb and test are using same username and password. Is it possible to create a different user and password for test  database?

**update**:

I have updated the script 01.sql to:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test`;
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But when I try to connect using DBeaver(username:newuser,password:password) get the error access denied.

However when I connect using username:root, password:root i can see the table created:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Any idea what i am doing wrong please?

Comment: You will need some external SQL scripts for such as features: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57266460/1292359

Comment: Thnks but is it possible assign each user to a databse with script?